# Strange behaviour of angularjs with Float32Arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typed-arrays

I have noticed some not so nice behaviour of angularjs when using Float32Array values.

Essentially I tested these three

```
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.n = 0.2; // Displays as 0.2
  $scope.arr1 = new Float32Array(1);
  $scope.arr1[0] = 0.2; // 0,20000000298023224
  $scope.arr2 = new Float64Array(1);
  $scope.arr2[0] = 0.2;  // Displays as 0.2
});
```

I do understand the problem with 0.2 being periodical as a binary fraction.

However, do you have any idea how to tell the *toString* method (or some other function) to take account for the lower precision and round the decimal when appropriate?

This is the directive that I added to make it a bit better (but still not quite):

```
.directive("numberfloat", function(){
  return {
    scope: {n: "=model"},
    template: '<input type="number" ng-model="m" ng-model-options="{getterSetter: true}"/>',
    link: function($scope){
      $scope.m = function(newVal){
        if(newVal){
          $scope.n = newVal;
        }
        return parseFloat($scope.n.toFixed(4));
      }
    }
  }
})
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/WqOwIHDF0iOS9YGe0mKj?p=preview

Comment: Ok, the real nasty thing is, that in the end even a Float64Array behaves differently when entering certain stuff - that is for instance it is not possible to have it contain just a minus sign. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`number` filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number) to fix the precision of the displayed numbers in the template itself, i.e., in the view layer itself.

e.g. `{{arr1[0] | number:2 }}` will fix the precision at 2 decimal places.

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/0pH9XAYlwoPTSDxjKTZ8?p=preview

Comment: Thank you, but this is the somehow obvious part - the trickier part is the other way, where it makes input rather impossible. I came up with the solution in the (now updated plunker) but once in a while it still renders unusable due to some large number that you are unable to edit at all.

I will probably do the hassle of internally storing a 64 bit number and just converting it whenever it is needed as a 32 bit one.